# Which upanishad contains the laxmi gayatri mantra?

Tags: vedas, mantras, upanishads, lakshmi, gayatri-mantra

Gayatri mantra which is chanted at the end of Sri sukta, which upanishad or Veda contains it?

The Mantra is this:

> ॐ म॒हा॒दे॒व्यै च॑ वि॒द्महे॑ विष्णुप॒त्नी च॑ धीमहि । तन्नो॑ लक्ष्मीः
>   प्रचो॒दया॓त् ॥ -- Om mahadevyai cha vidmahe vishnupatni cha dhimahi
>   tanno lakshmi prachodayath ||

Comment: @BhargavRao wasn't able to find laxmi gayatri in those gayatris from upanishads.

Comment: @AnuragSingh which "upanishad".

Comment: Which is that mantra that you chant at the end of the Sri Sukta? U need to specify the mantra..

Comment: @Rickross "ॐ म॒हा॒दे॒व्यै च॑ वि॒द्महे॑ विष्णुप॒त्नी च॑ धीमहि । तन्नो॑ लक्ष्मीः प्रचो॒दया॓त् ॥" some new age Vedics like rakesh joshi/fierce lord are calling this as interpolation, I don't believe in that offcource as I believe in the timeline of puranas, I want to find out where this mantra is from if it's from one of the ancient upanishads my problem will be solved.

Comment: Ok.. Did u chk the mahanaryana? It has Gayatris of several deities..

Comment: But this mantra is obviously not part of the Sri Sukta.. They just add it at the end.. Like here: http://greenmesg.org/stotras/lakshmi/sri_suktam.php  But several other stuffs are also added at the end there, which are not part of the Sukta.. @AnubhavJha

Comment: @Rickross so Sri is not lakshmi? But she is called golden complexioned, with elephants and lotus, progeny of kardama she is same diety as laxmi of Vishnu right?

Comment: I  am not commenting on that.. i am just saying that this particular Gayatri is not part of the Sri Sukta mantras.. They add it at the end..to finish things off..  Some other scriptures will definitely have it, either the Puranas or the Upanishads or

Comment: @AnubhavJha in the above link given by Rickross , verse 25 to 36 are additions from other stotras. In fact verse 27 to 28 are actually one whole verse, but they have divided a whole verse into two separate verses.

Comment: @AnubhavJha The question about Gayatris of almost all he gods is covered there. It is asked already. So, it is a duplicate.